# Why comparing Timestamp and date in Firebird result in weird value?

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm comparing some dates and times and found that I do not understand [Firebird Date Literals](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-date-literals/) and [their conversions](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-conversion.html) as I thought so.

Please, see this query:

```
SELECT 
    iif('2016-01-25' <= '2016-01-25', 1, 0) AS TSCASE,
    iif('2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= '2016-01-25', 1, 0) AS TSCASE1,
    iif('2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= cast('2016-01-25' as timestamp), 1, 0) AS TSCASE2,
    iif(cast('2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' as timestamp) <= '2016-01-25', 1, 0) AS TSCASE3,
    iif('2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= '2016-01-25 00:00:00.000', 1, 0) AS TSCASE4,
    iif('2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= '2016-01-25 23:59:59.999', 1, 0) AS TSCASE5,
    iif('2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= '2016-01-25  23:59:59.999', 1, 0) AS TSCASE6,
    iif('2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= cast('2016-01-25  23:59:59.999' as timestamp), 1, 0) AS TSCASE7
FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

I'm expecting that every column result was 1. But this is the result:

```
TSCASE  TSCASE1 TSCASE2 TSCASE3 TSCASE4 TSCASE5 TSCASE6 TSCASE7
       1      0       1       1       1       1       0       1
```

So why `'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= '2016-01-25'` is false but, when I do any `cast` to `TIMESTAMP`, is true?

Also why `'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= '2016-01-25 23:59:59.999'` and `'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= cast('2016-01-25  23:59:59.999' as timestamp)` are true, but `'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= '2016-01-25  23:59:59.999'` is false?

Please note the extra space between the date and time in these last two expressions. I did think that the extra space would not change the result as you can see in this quote also from the [first link](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-date-literals/):

> White Space in Date Literals
>
> Spaces or tabs can appear between elements. A date part must be separated from a time part by at least one space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are not comparing timestamps and dates in most of your expressions. Instead you are comparing **string** (`CHAR`) literals.

To answer your specific inquiries:

1. `'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= '2016-01-25'` is false because in string sorting `2016-01-25` comes before `2016-01-25 00:00:00.000`
2. `'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= '2016-01-25  23:59:59.999'` is false because `2016-01-25  23:59:59.999` has a second space before the time part, and in string sorting a space comes before a `0`.

To use date or timestamp literals, you either need to explicitly prefix the string literal with `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`, or you need to use a cast, otherwise it is just a string. Change your query to the one below and you do get your expected values:

```sql
SELECT 
    iif(DATE'2016-01-25' <= DATE'2016-01-25', 1, 0) AS TSCASE,
    iif(TIMESTAMP'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= DATE'2016-01-25', 1, 0) AS TSCASE1,
    iif(TIMESTAMP'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= cast('2016-01-25' as timestamp), 1, 0) AS TSCASE2,
    iif(cast('2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' as timestamp) <= DATE'2016-01-25', 1, 0) AS TSCASE3,
    iif(TIMESTAMP'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= TIMESTAMP'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000', 1, 0) AS TSCASE4,
    iif(TIMESTAMP'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= TIMESTAMP'2016-01-25 23:59:59.999', 1, 0) AS TSCASE5,
    iif(TIMESTAMP'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= TIMESTAMP'2016-01-25  23:59:59.999', 1, 0) AS TSCASE6,
    iif(TIMESTAMP'2016-01-25 00:00:00.000' <= cast('2016-01-25  23:59:59.999' as timestamp), 1, 0) AS TSCASE7
FROM RDB$DATABASE
```